# C# Static instance members for each inherited class

Tags: c#, inheritance, static

Consider the following example:

```
interface IPropertyCollection
{
    public MethodWrapper GetPropertySetterByName(string name);
    //<<-- I want the implementation from A and B merged into here somehow
}
class A : IPropertyCollection
{
    static PropertyMap properties = new PropertyMap(typeof(A));
    public MethodWrapper GetPropertySetterByName(string name)
    {
        return properties.SomeFunc(name);
    }
}
class B : IPropertyCollection
{
    static PropertyMap properties = new PropertyMap(typeof(B));
    public MethodWrapper GetPropertySetterByName(string name)
    {
        return properties.SomeFunc(name);
    }
}
```

I want to have a static member in each class keeping track of things in that class only and i want it to behave exactly the same for every class, but with different content. Each static member should only keep track of one single class. I want to be able to get access to the classes' static member by just having an instance of any IPropertyCollection.

Something like this:

```
    IPropertyCollection a = new A();
    IPropertyCollection b = new B();
    a.GetPropertySetterByName("asdfsj");  //Should end up in static A.properties 
    b.GetPropertySetterByName("asdfsj");  //Should end up in static B.properties
```

Now this will work with my example code but i don't want to repeat all those lines inside A and B and 50 other classes.

Comment: "Static instance methods" is contradictory.  It's either static or instance.  What you really mean is that you want a static member that will be initialized dependent on the sub-class, right?

Comment: Seems to me as good candidate for abstract class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a (curiously recurring) generic common base class:

```
abstract class Base<T> : IPropertyCollection where T : Base<T> {
  static PropertyMap properties = new PropertyMap(typeof(T));
  public MethodWrapper GetPropertySetterByName(string name) {
      return properties.SomeFunc(name);
  }
}

class A : Base<A> { }
class B : Base<B> { }
```

Since the base class is generic, a different "version" of its static members will be "generated" for each different type parameter.

Just be careful with [evil dogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx) :-)

```
class Evil : Base<A> { } // will share A's static member...
```

Comment: What is the name of this design pattern? If I were to describe it to another developer, I would call it what?

Comment: @VinceHorst: it's similar to the C++ [curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Answer (score 4):

[Static members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx) can't be inherited. They belong to the class they are declared on.

Comment: do you know why I was notified on your comment?  I certainly didn't downvote, and my name isn't Downvoter.  Is "Downvoter" a special value that mass notifies everyone attached to the comment stream?

Comment: @AdamRackis - No, it isn't. You probably got notified because you were the only commenter, the system assumed I was asking you...