# C# inheritance - save reference to last instance

Tags: c#, inheritance, static

I just came up with a really odd problem and I wasn't able to figure out how to solve it.

I have 3 classes, the class A is the base for B and C, that is:

```
class A { ... }
class B : A { ... }
class C : B { ... }
```

Now I would like to have a static property in these classes that stores the last object of each classes created, for example:

```
class A
{
    static public A lastInstance;
}

class B : A
{
    public B()
    {
        lastInstance = this;
    }
}

class C : A
{
    public C()
    {
        lastInstance = this;
    }
}
```

What I would like to achieve is to be able to retrieve an instance for each subclass, for example:

```
var v1 = new B();
var v2 = new C();

var v3 = B.lastInstance;    // v3 == v1 and v3 != v2
var v4 = C.lastInstance;    // v4 == v2 and v4 != v3
```

Is it possible anyhow?

The only approach that seems promising to me shown in [C# Static instance members for each inherited class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142768/c-sharp-static-instance-members-for-each-inherited-class/8142828#8142828): is it really the only chance I have to avoid defining a static member manually for each class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this could be done with `Dictionary` and that's the only way i can think of right now:

```
class A {
    static Dictionary<Type, A> _LastInstances = new Dictionary<Type, A>(); // because every subclass will inherit from A
    public static A LastInstance {
        get {
            if ( _LastInstances.ContainsKey(GetType()) ) {
                return _LastInstances[GetType()];
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected set {
            if ( _LastInstances.ContainsKey(GetType()) ) {
                _LastInstances[GetType()] = value;
            } else {
                _LastInstances.Add(GetType(), value);
            }
        }
}

class B : A {
    public B(){
        LastInstance = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: I chose your solution as the answer since it seems to be the more general and scalable! Thank you very much for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

At first: yes you can. But you missed two points with your implementation.

1. As you declared the `lastInstance` as public in class A every derived class can use it. As you declared it as static every instance of A will copy itself into it. But so will every instance of B, C and every other class with id derived from A: they all use **the same instance**. Thus the last instatiated class is saved and everything instantiated before is overwritten.

To overcome this, you must have a static property `LastInstance` (I switched to my naming convention) **on every class**, which you can accomplish by using the `new` modifier on derived classes

```cs
public class A
{
   public static A LastInstance { get; private set; }
   ...
}

public class B : A
{
   public static new B LastInstance { get; private set; }
   ...
}
```

But you're not done with that alone, because

2. When you create a new instance of B the (default-)construstor first makes a call into the construtor of A. Thus a reference to any already created instance of a base class is overwritten by the currently created instance of the derived class. So your constructors should look like this:

```cs
public class A
{
   public static A LastInstance { get; private set; }
   public A()
   {
      if (this.GetType() == typeof(A))
      {
         LastInstance = this;
      }
   }
}

public class B : A
{
   public static new B LastInstance { get; private set; }
   public B()
   {
      if (this.GetType() == typeof(B))
      {
         LastInstance = this;
      }
   }
}
```

This way you will get the correct lastly created instance (if any) in each classes static `LastInstance`.

Hope this helps

Comment: Your second statement is false because even if it makes a call to constructor from derived class it still uses the instance class type in `GetType()`. Some days ago there was even a good example shown in SO. The only issue with your second example is that when you remove `if` statement from ctor you will have the same instance for every `LastInstance`.

Comment: If I get you right, you are wrong. The statement (2.) is correct (and tested). If you have `var b = new B();` the call chain is 
1. enter ctor B, 
2. execute body of ctor A (with `B` as this.GetType) 
3. execute the body of ctor B. 
And yes, the purpose of the `if` statement is to filter out the unwanted (derived) instances. But I thought, this was obvious.

Comment: What i meant is that `GetType()` will always return the instantiated type so for `B.GetType()` it will be the same type in every constructor `B => A`. I'm not saing that it does not work because it is working fine. Maybe my comment was unclear or I missunderstood second example's description.

Comment: Intended was: you need the `if` (at least in base classes constructors) **because** the `GetType` results in the instatiated class and not in the class which constructors code is currently run. So, it seems we agree.

Answer (score 1):

Because static members aren't inherited, you won't be able to access B.lastInstance if class A defines lastInstance. The suggestion you linked to seems reasonable. Although I don't have enough information on why you're attempting this, you could consider using a factory class that holds onto the latest created object.

Here's an example. This is not a good long term solution if you plan to have many classes deriving from A.

```
class HoldLastKnownFactory
{
    B CreateB() { ... }
    C CreateC() { ... }
    B LastB { get {...} }
    C LastC { get {...} }
}
```