# How to make a string different for each instance of a class

Tags: c#

So, I have a public `partial` class called **Condensed**. Each instance of condensed is supposed to have its own file path which it will load data from, which I tried to create by having a private `static` string called **Path** I then create 6 instances of `Condensed`, but I found out that when I change one of the values of `Path` that all of the instances of `Condensed` set their value of `Path` to the most recent one

```
public partial class Condensed : UserControl
{
    private static string Path;

    public Sender Export()
    {
           //this uses Path to Load data then return it to the main class
    }

    public void Load(string path)
    {
          Path = path
    }
}
```

And then inside my main class I do as follows:

```
public class Main
{
    public void Load_Condensed()
    {
         condensed1.Load(Paths[0]);
         condensed2.Load(Paths[1]);
         condensed3.Load(Paths[2]);
         condensed4.Load(Paths[3]);
         condensed5.Load(Paths[4]);
         condensed6.Load(Paths[5]);
    }

    private void exportToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<Condensed> Pokemon = new List<Condensed>
        {
            condensed1.Export(),
            condensed2.Export(),
            condensed3.Export(),
            condensed4.Export(),   //Loads all of the data from calling Export()
            condensed5.Export(),
            condensed6.Export()
        };

        Export(Condensed);  //Sends the data
    }
}
```

`Paths[]` is just an array of file paths stored as a public array of strings.

Basically I want each instance of Condensed to have its own unique string Path which can be used inside of the instance it is created for, how do i do this?

Comment: Take out the `static` keyword in the field:

Comment: Read what is static and when to use it.

Comment: @stuartd i've already tried that, it doesnt work :L

Comment: You can check [my answer on similiar topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40999880/c-sharp-inheritance-save-reference-to-last-instance/41000102#41000102)

Comment: @mybirthname how would i go about doing that?

Comment: Why do you say that without static _it doesn't work_? what happens when you remove _static_?

Comment: @Pikoh this is C# not VB.Net so names are case sensitive, and that's not the problem.

Comment: Is it a multi-threaded application ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Path`-field is `static`, which means it gets shared between all instances.
Modify it to an instance field to have it different for each instance:

```
public partial class Condensed : UserControl
{
    private string Path; // No static here

    public Sender Export()
    {
           this uses Path to Load data then return it to the main class
    }

    public void Load(string path)
    {
          Path = path
    }
}
```

The fact that it is a partial class, doesn't really have anything to do with it. Partial classes just mean that you can define the class in separate files (in this case because it's a usercontrol that needs to set up some code for the UI)

Comment: The Path then shows as null when i call on it later

Comment: Where do you call it from? If you use it like this, it shouldn't be `null`.

Comment: Saw your update. If `Path` is `null` when you call export, it can mean two things: either you assign a `null` value to somewhere between setting it in the `Load` method and calling the `Export` method or you are passing in a `null` value to begin with. We'd need more code to see what's going on.

Comment: If you try to access this field in code from *outside* of `Condensed` class then you might consider to change the access modifier to `public`

Comment: Closest to the correct answer, i had to add some validation but this works :)

Answer (score 3):

The `static` is causing your problem because it uses ***shared*** memory between all instances of the `Condensed` class, just remove the `static` keyword from your property definition.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var condensed1 = new Condensed() { FilePath = "/filepath1/" };
            var condensed2 = new Condensed() { FilePath = "/filepath2/blah/" };
            var condensed3 = new Condensed() { FilePath = "/filepath3/blah/blah/" };

            Console.WriteLine(condensed1.FilePath);
            Console.WriteLine(condensed2.FilePath);
            Console.WriteLine(condensed3.FilePath);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public partial class Condensed
    {
        public string FilePath { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Add new constructor like

```
  public Condensed(string path)
{
      Path = path
}
```

And when you create an instance of Condensed class, call it like

```
Condensed c1 = new Condensed("C/Desktop/blabla");
c1.Export();
```

Comment: That does not help. His field is static so it won't make a difference

Comment: I create the condensed classes in a designer (they are a form which i use inside another form) so i cant do this as i never "create" an instance of Condensed in my main code